# Excel Cell Indirect Reference

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Just curious on excel to search for a value and return the address/location of the cell.  For example if i had B9= 5 and used vlookup to find 5 rather than returning the value i would like B9 returned.  Also in this case how do i use that reference for another formula rather than the actual value within the cell.  Using an example again i would like my next formula to click on the value 5 cell but rather than using 5 in the formula to use the B9 cell reference.  Is there anyway to do this?  Ive tried using indirect, vlookup, match index etc and  no luck.

Comment: ① `=ADDRESS(MATCH(5,B:B, 0), COLUMN(B:B), 4)` ② formulas do not 'click on the value 5 cell'.

Answer (score 1):

**First question:**

If you insist on `VLOOKUP()`, it gets cumbersome:

1. Create an auxiliary column C with this: `=CELL("address";B1)`
2. Now you can use `=VLOOKUP(5;B:C;2;FALSE)` and you should get `$B$9`

If you just want to know "In which cell is the value 5?" you can use @Jeeped's solution: `=ADDRESS(MATCH(5,B:B,0),COLUMN(B:B),4)` (note that the value `5` is hardcoded here). You should get `B9`

If you already know the column (i.e. `B`) your question is "In which *row* is the value 5?" Answer: `=MATCH(5;B:B)` which gives you `9`. To prepend `B`, use `="B"&MATCH(5;B:B)`

**Second question:**

I guess you're looking for `INDIRECT()`. If you write one of the above formulas in, say, `D1` (or even type in "B9" by hand into D1), you can use `=INDIRECT(D1)`. This transforms the string "B9" back into a cell reference, which means you get B9's value back, i.e. `5`